# Executar ECHO sem interpretar HTML

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tenho um valor no banco de dados mysql que contem alguns comandos em html como:

> `<b>Olá</b>`
>
> `<br>`
>
> Outros...

Preciso que quando eu mostre o valor usando `<?php echo $row_rs['original']; ?>` apareça exatamente como esta no BD, sem a interpretação do HTML.

Ao inves de aparecer assim:

> **Olá**

apareça assim:

> `<b>Olá</b>`

Obrigado.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities).

Ex.: `<?php echo htmlentities($row_rs['original']); ?>`

Comment: como faço para limitar e echo a 35 caracteres?

Comment: @Tiago para limitar: echo substr(htmlentities($row_rs['original']), 0, 35);

Comment: valeu, muito obrigado!

Comment: +1 pela solução correta. Vale mencionar a quem não conhece bem as tecnologias envolvidas que na verdade o que está sendo feito não é evitar que se interprete o HTML, mas sim dando _escape_ no HTML com mais HTML :).